# Is it possible to use a string in a SELECT or WHERE statement in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm processing some textual data and I transform them into interpretable commands that would be used as argument for a WHERE statement but I get a string and I don't know how to use it.

For example from the string :

```
'c_programme_nom == "2-Broke-Girls"'
```

I get :

```
"F.col('name').like('%2-Broke-Girls%')"
```

But I get a string and I would like to use it as a parameter in a WHERE statement.

The expected result would be :

```
df.where(F.col('name').like('%2-Broke-Girls%'))
```

I don't know if there is a way to do it.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want

Comment: You can use `exec()` in python to execute a string which contains code

Comment: `exec("print(10)")` will give out `10`

Comment: Ty thats what I was looking for, sry If I was unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking to execute strings containing code:

You can use [`exec`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/) in python:

*exec() function is used for the dynamic execution of Python program which can either be a string or object code. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed unless a syntax error occurs and if it is an object code, it is simply executed.*

```
exec('print("The sum of 5 and 10 is", (5+10))')
# The sum of 5 and 10 is 15
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what I was looking for